# JoinColumn default behaviour

Tags: jpa

can you explain what is default behaviour of @JoinColumn annotation when it's applaied to a field without any other relation annotation.

```
@Entity
class Employee{
  @Id int id;

  @JoinColumn(name = "man_id")
  Employee manager;

}
```

how does jpa proceed it? if i.e. employee is many side of onetomany biderectional relation with department, where fetchtype lazy specified on both sides, when I access(ask collection for size) getEmployees property of department entity, eclipcelink generates sql and selects all records from employee entity also.

```
SELECT ID FROM deps WHERE (ID = ?)
SELECT ID, name, man_id, dep_id FROM emps WHERE (dep_id = ?)
additional requests
SELECT ID, name, man_id, dep_id FROM emps WHERE (ID = ?)
SELECT ID, name, man_id, dep_id FROM emps WHERE (ID = ?)
SELECT ID, name, man_id, dep_id FROM emps WHERE (ID = ?)
.................
```

If I mark this property with @OnetoOne(which is actually i mean) relation and set fetchtype lazy, everything "works correct" meaning manager property is not fetched until I ask employee for it.

```
SELECT ID FROM deps WHERE (ID = ?)
SELECT ID, name, man_id, dep_id FROM deps WHERE (dep_id = ?)
```

Comment: default behaviour ? it defines what the column is. BUT IT IS OBLIGATORY to put a OneToOne/ManyToOne on a single valued relation field ... which is what defines the "behaviour"

Comment: Hi, I enclosed the sql code generated by eclipcelink, in case when I dont apply any relation type. so it is working, So "obligatory" in this case seems to be more like "should"?

Answer (score 0):

By not putting a relationship type/annotation, actually means JPA would not treat your attribute as an entity.

Perhaps, you already had your schema in place that's why your queries are working. However, I experimented on this and started with a fresh database. The behavior is different from what you expected. With Hibernate, my chosen JPA provider (with `hbm2ddl` property set to `create`), it generated the ff. schema:

```
create table Employee (
    id bigint not null auto_increment,
    manager tinyblob,
    name varchar(255),
    primary key (id)
)
```

Since my manager is an `Employee` class implementing `Serializable` interface, it was by default mapped to a BLOB type column.

Also by not mapping it with any relationship annotations, means that there will be no foreign key constraints applied to your manager column.

Comment: hi, you stated By not putting a relationship type/annotation, actually means JPA would not treat your attribute as an entity. I think it depends on persistence provider, eclipsekink seems to treat it as an entity anyway. I also noted that, these additional sql selects are only executed for those employees there man_id is not null. Anyway it's not a good practice to not mark a @joincolumn without any relation. and it seems like the bahaviour is up from persistence provider.